# Codeline triggering randomly dispatch_async

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

In my secondView I do this:

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);

    dbq = [[dbqueries alloc] init];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"abc" object:nil];
    //disabling a button and turning a progressView in the mainView on

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        //WORK
    });
}
```

The notification disables a button and causes a progressView(in the progressView there is an ActivityIndicator) on the mainView to start.
In the area, where work is done, a method is called 3 to 6 times and if they are all done, I send another notification to the mainView to enable the button and to stop the progressView.
Now the weird thing is, that the button gets enabled at the right time but the progressView stops randomly after a few seconds

```
- (void)enableStartButton
{
    NSLog(@"enableStartButton");

    self.startARButton.enabled = YES;
    [self.progressView setHidden:YES];

    [[self.progressView.subviews objectAtIndex:0] stopAnimating];
}
```

I really don't know whats going on here, thanks in advance!

Comment: When updating the progress view from the background thread are you shipping those calls back to the main thread? If not, you need to be doing that. NSNotifications are, by default, delivered on the thread which posts them, so going through NSNotificationCenter is not, in itself, enough to satisfy the threading requirements of UIKit in this case.